# Prove that $\text{Adj}(AB) = \text{Adj}(B)\text{Adj}(A)$ for $A,B$ rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to show that $\text{Adj}(AB) = \text{Adj}(B)\text{Adj}(A)$, where  $A$ is an $N$x$M$ matrix, and $B$ is an $M$x$K$ matrix, and $\text{Adj}(A)$ denotes the adjoint of $A$.

I have a feeling that I should expand the matrix multiplication into the sum, and then it I should be able to some multiplication since the the indeces are just simple numbers and I can move them around. But I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Okay, I think I got it now! Assuming $C = AB$, I have that

$$
C_{ij} = \sum\limits_{k} A_{ik}B_{kj}
$$

Then

$$
\text{Adj}(C_{ij}) = \text{Adj} \left( \sum\limits_{k} A_{ik}B_{kj} \right) = \sum\limits_{k} \text{Adj}(A_{ik})\text{Adj}(B_{kj}) = \sum\limits_{k} A^*_{ki}B^*_{jk} = \sum\limits_{k} B^*_{jk}A^*_{ki} = \text{Adj}(B)\text{Adj}(A)
$$

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Adj}$ here?

Comment: The adjoint of the matrix.

Comment: Which one? (There are at least two, and they have nothing to do with each other.)

Comment: Taking the complex conjugate of each index and then switch columns and rows. The book I'm reading is "Modern Quantum Chemistry" by Szabo&Ostlund.

Comment: Ah. Hint: $C_{ji} = \sum_k A_{jk} B_{ki}$, so that $\overline{C_{ji}} = \overline{\sum_k A_{jk} B_{ki}} = \sum_k \overline{A_{jk}} \cdot \overline{B_{ki}} = \sum_k \overline{B_{ki}} \cdot \overline{A_{jk}}$. Now compare this with the $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry of $B^* A^*$.

Answer (score 4):

### For general Hilbert spaces

$\newcommand{\adjun}{^{*}}$I denote $\operatorname{Adj}(A)$ as $A\adjun$ and $(x,y)_{H_i}$ is the scalarproduct of the Hilbertspace $H_i$. So $A: H_2 \to H_3$ and $B: H_1 \to H_2$.
\begin{align*}
(ABx,y)_{H_3} = (Bx,A\adjun y)_{H_2} = (x,B\adjun A\adjun y)_{H_1}
\end{align*}
So by definition $(AB)\adjun =B\adjun A\adjun$

---

### Concrete for matrices in finite vectorspaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times k}$ then $AB = \mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$ and
\begin{align*}
(AB)_{i,j} = \sum_{l = 1}^m A_{i,l}\cdot B_{l,j}
\end{align*}
Additionally we know by your definition that $((AB)\adjun)_{i,j} = \overline{AB_{j,i}}$ where for $z= x + \mathrm{i}y \in \mathbb{C}$ $\overline{z}= x - \mathrm{i} y$ (Complex conjugate). We know that the Complex conjugate is a homomorphism for the field $\mathbb{C}$. This means amongst others

- $\overline{z_1 + z_2} = \overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2}$
- $\overline{z_1 \cdot z_2} = \overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{z_2}$

Endowed with this knowledge we have
\begin{align*}
((AB)\adjun)_{i,j} = \overline{AB_{j,i}}  = \overline{\sum_{l = 1}^m A_{j,l} \cdot B_{l,i}} = \sum_{l = 1}^m \overline{A_{j,l}} \cdot\overline{B_{l,i}}
\end{align*}
On the other hand we have $(A\adjun)_{i,j} = \overline{A_{j,i}}$ and the same counts for $B$
\begin{align*}
(B\adjun A\adjun)_{i,j} = \sum_{l=1}^m (B\adjun)_{i,l}\cdot(A\adjun)_{l,j} = 
\sum_{l=1}^m \overline{B_{l,i}}\cdot\overline{A_{j,l}}
=\sum_{l = 1}^m \overline{A_{j,l}} \cdot\overline{B_{l,i}}
\end{align*}
and this does the trick :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your notation is a bit beyond my level. Cannot this be shown more "mechanically"?

Comment: I can do it but you have to edit your question in order to show what your setting exactly is and what your definitions are...

Comment: I am not able to type but it can be proved by using Reversal  Law  for Inverses :  If  A,  B  are  any two non-singular  matrices  of the  same  order,  then  AB  is also non-singular  and $ \text(AB)^{−1}  =  \text(B)^{-1} \text(A)^{−1}$ i.e., the inverse of  a product is the product  of the inverses taken in the reverse  order.

Comment: Maybe "Proof" was not the correct word. I don't need the formal proof, but just to see how the order switches naturally from taking the adjoint of the matrix product.

Comment: @Yoda I hope this is what you have excepted.

Answer (score 1):

Let us remember that, where $A_{n \times n}$ is a matrix,
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\adjoint}{adj}
A \cdot \adjoint{(A)} = \adjoint{(A)} \cdot A = |A| \cdot I_{n}
$$
Hence
$$
\adjoint{(AB)} \cdot AB = |AB| \cdot I_{n} = |A|\cdot |B| \cdot I_{n}
\\
\implies \adjoint{(AB)} \cdot AB \cdot \adjoint(B) = |A|\cdot |B| \cdot \adjoint(B)
\\
= \adjoint{(AB)} \cdot A \cdot |B| \cdot I_{n} = |A|\cdot |B| \cdot \adjoint(B) 
\\
\implies |B| \cdot \adjoint{(AB)} \cdot A \cdot \adjoint(A) = |A|\cdot |B| \cdot \adjoint(B) \cdot \adjoint(A)
\\
=  |B| \cdot  \adjoint{(AB)} \cdot |A| \cdot I_{n} = |A|\cdot |B| \cdot \adjoint(B) \cdot \adjoint(A)
\\
=  |A|\cdot |B| \cdot  \adjoint{(AB)} = |A|\cdot |B| \cdot \adjoint(B) \cdot \adjoint(A)
$$
If neither $A$ nor $B$ is singular i.e. $0\notin \{|A|,|B|\}$, then we may simply divide on both sides to obtain
$$
\boxed{
  \adjoint{(AB)} = \adjoint(B) \cdot \adjoint(A)
}
$$
If either of $A$ or $B$ is singular, we make them non-singular by applying a limit on them. We may do this since **$\adjoint$ is a continuous function** on the entries of the pre-image. The details of this been left as an exercise for the reader. :)